# Replicate functionality to double click headphone button

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, headphones

You can use the headphones button to pause or play, or skip to the next song.

Has anyone figured out how to replicate this functionality on a Windows desktop or a MacBook Pro with players like Pandora or Spotify?